# Is the question "Is Gina Haspel wanted in Europe?" sufficiently improved to re-open?

Tags: discussion, notability

The question [Is Gina Haspel wanted in Europe?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/40935/is-gina-haspel-wanted-in-europe) was closed for lacking a notable source. I've edited it to trace how the claim in question came to my attention. Is this sufficient to get the question re-opened? If not, what sort of source is notable-enough?

Answer (score 2):

This is a little after the fact as the person you mentioned had since deleted the tweet and rescinded the claim, but in general when you ask a question on the site, you should link to the notable source making the claim, instead of just saying they made the claim.  Doing so serves several purposes.

1. Prevents potential respondents from having to dig just to find the claim in the first place.
2. Allows us to identify any misconceptions between what is claimed in the question vs. what the notable source said
3. Shows people on the site that the question was asked in good faith, instead of trying to send us on a wild goose chase to find something that may or may not exist.

---

In your case, linking to the Tweet where he made the claim would have been sufficient, assuming that the person in question is notable enough.

The general process going from closed to reopen in this case would have been

1. Edit the question, adding a link to the tweet in question that claimed what you were claiming in the question.
2. The question would get nominated for re-opening.
3. If enough users with a high enough reputation score agree that the question should be re-opened, then it would appear back on the main list.

In your particular case, it doesn't seem like it would be worthwhile to re-open the question, particularly because the original source has since retracted the claim.

---

Note that there are some much older questions on the site that do not follow this rule.  The rules of this site have changed over the years to require links to notable claimants, whereas older questions did not require said beliefs.